# How to subtract and get difference between time inputs in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon, laravel-6

I'm building a small app in laravel, the app has a date and time inputs which i use to calculate the price of a given task. I have successfully calculated the date difference, now i'm trying to get the difference between two selected times which is in PM and AM formats but i'm stuck.
What i want to achieve is, when a user selects a time as the example below; i get the time difference in hours and if it is 3 or more hours i give a certain penalty, please help!

```
 array:4 [▼
  "pickup_date" => "2019-09-13"
  "pickup_time" => "11:37 AM"
  "dropoff_date" => "2019-09-14"
  "dropoff_time" => "10:37 PM"
 ]
```

Comment: Anything beside that, you need or unable to make it work, let me know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Cabon `diff()`

In tinker it will be like

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.5 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-09-13 11:37 AM')->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('20
19-09-11 10:23 PM'))
=> DateInterval {#3080
     interval: - 1d 13:14:00.0,
   }
>>>
```

You can use it in your code.

Difference in hours

```
> \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-09-13 11:37 AM')->diffInHours(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-09-11 10:2
3 PM'))
=> 37
```

your if conditional can be

```
$diff = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-09-13 11:37 AM')->diffInHours(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-09-11 10:2
    3 PM'));
```

and then

```
if ( $diff > 3 ) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: @princeallan what you actually want, days diff, week diff, human readable diff etc?

Comment: This works fine after integrating but my problem is to check those hours in my code, i want to us it in an if statement

Comment: @princeallan you can convert it to any format you want, can you post your conditional?

Comment: @princeallan edited my answer, that shows diff in hours.

Comment: I will use your example, i want to say @if( hours > 3 ) { give a penalty } else { perform normal logic }. This means in your example, the person has 13 hours on top of that full day hence he will be be fined since he has more than 3 hours of the the next day

Comment: @princeallan again edited my answer, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, i realized i needed days too so i did @if($diff > 24 && $diff % 24 && $diff > 3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `diffInHours` for the same,

```
$pickUp = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i A', '2019-09-13 11:37 AM');//->toDateTimeString(); 
$dropOff = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i A', '2019-09-14 10:37 PM');//->toDateTimeString(); 
echo $dropOff->diffInHours($pickUp);//->format('%H'); // Output: 35
```

Answer (score 1):

Carbon is included in laravel by default,
In your controller make sure you import carbon

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

and in the specific method you can do this :

```
$dropoff = Carbon::parse($request->dropoff_date .' '. $request->dropoff_time);
$pickup = Carbon::parse($request->pickup_date .' '. $request->pickup_time);

if($dropoff->diffInHours($pickup) > 3){
  // penalty
}
// rest
```

More details in [Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $start_date = new DateTime('2012-09-01 04:10:58');
 $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('2012-09-11 10:25:00'));
 echo $since_start->days.' days total<br>';
 echo $since_start->y.' years<br>';
 echo $since_start->m.' months<br>';
 echo $since_start->d.' days<br>';
 echo $since_start->h.' hours<br>';
 echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
 echo $since_start->s.' seconds<br>';
```

It will shows the output
x days total
y years
z months
a days
b hours
c minutes
d seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the diff seconds

```
$times = array(
    "pickup_date" => "2019-09-13",
    "pickup_time" => "11:37 AM",
    "dropoff_date" => "2019-09-14",
    "dropoff_time" => "10:37 PM"
);
$diff_in_seconds = strtotime($times["dropoff_date"] . " " . $times["dropoff_time"]) - strtotime($times["pickup_date"] . " " . $times["pickup_time"]);
if($diff_in_seconds > 10800){   // 3h -> 10800s
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use `Carbon` package, you can use below solution, This is procedural/functional way, PHP also have Object oriented classes to achieve same.

```
$time = [
  "pickup_date" => "2019-09-13",
  "pickup_time" => "11:37 AM",
  "dropoff_date" => "2019-09-14",
  "dropoff_time" => "10:37 PM",
 ];

extract($time);

$pickup_datetime = date_create_from_format ( 'Y-m-d h:i a',$pickup_date.' '.$pickup_time);
$dropoff_datetime = date_create_from_format ( 'Y-m-d h:i a',$dropoff_date.' '.$dropoff_time);

$interval = date_diff($dropoff_datetime,$pickup_datetime);
$hours = date_interval_format($interval, '%h');
```